# what is the complement of the language L={ww : w ∈{a,b}* }

Tags: automata

The given language is not CFL ,it is CSL and CFL is not closed under complement operation ,Now I am not getting how to find it's complement ,please tell the approach .

Comment: Are you trying to describe the language, or are you trying to determine where it falls in the hierarchy (regular, context-free, context-sensitive, unrestricted)?

Comment: I am not getting how to find the complement of this CSL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L'$ be the complement, $L'=\{a,b\}^*\setminus L$. Clearly every word in $L$ has even length, so every word of $\{a,b\}^*$ with odd length must be in $L_1$. Let

$$R=\left\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:|w|\text{ is odd}\right\}\;;$$

then $R\subseteq L_1$.

It remains to determine what word of even length are in $L_1$. These are precisely the words in $\{a,b\}^*$ that can be written in the form $uv$, where $u\ne v$ and $|u|=|v|$. Thus

$$L_1=R\cup\left\{uv\in\{a,b\}^*:u\ne v\text{ and }|u|=|v|\right\}\;.$$

Comment: will the grammar for L1 be like S-->A0A / B1B , A-->1A , B -->0B so that u≠v and |u|=|v|

Comment: @Radha: I’ve not tried to prove it, but I strongly suspect that $L_1$ is not context free. (It definitely is at least context-sensitive.) Your proposal definitely does not generate $L_1$, or even $L_1\setminus R$.

Comment: I was talking only about second part in which we have {uv∈{a,b}*:u≠v and |u|=|v|}.

Comment: @Radha: Yes, $L_1\setminus R$. But if you experiment a bit, you’ll find that your grammar doesn’t generate that language.

Comment: yes you are right so then how to make both the length of u and v same ?

Comment: @Radha: I can see how to build a context-sensitive grammar that would do the job, but the details would be a pain to work out.

Comment: @brian-m-scott It looks like $L_1$ is context-free. See [Show that $\{ xy \mid |x| = |y|, x \not= y \}$ is context-free](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-∣-x-y-x-≠-y-is-context-free/14550#14550)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Thanks; I rather thought so but was too lazy to work out the details, since it wasn’t needed. Raphael’s grammar is a lot neater than the approach that I had in mind.